# Google Ads API: Is it possible to extract comparison data?

Tags: api, google-ads-api

I've been tasked to extract the period comparison data from Google Ads.
At the moment a user can select a comparison date period in the ads.google.com UI, to see percentage growth of their ads, from one period to another.

I'd like to extract these comparison percentages from their API.

**Does anyone know if this is even possible, or do I have to calculate them myself?**

I've read through the API docs, but I'm afraid I missed something.

[image of google ads ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EgDX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. Unfortunately it's not possible. I had to do it myself. Which of course starts you off on your time series storage journey. Let me know if you need any pointers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I ended up make 2 seperate api calls, 1 for each time period. I then did a simple percentage calculation from one number to another. 
What do you mean with time series storage?